# \frac{}{} not rendering to github flavored markdown with quarto

Tags: quarto, github-flavored-markdown

I'm using quarto to render a `.qmd` file to github flavored markdown, however all the equations that are using `\frac{}{}` are not getting rendered. This is what I mean:

```
---
title: Some title
format: gfm
---

$$H_{0}:\:\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}=0$$         
$$H_{1}:\:\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\neq0$$

$$d=\frac{\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}}{\sigma}$$

$$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}}{2}}$$

Sin embargo, si ambos grupos tienen grandes diferencias de tamaño, $n_{1}\neq n_{2}$, entonces se usa la desviación estándar entre cada grupo (*pooled standard deviation*) en lugar de $\sigma$.
```

[image: output]

Which is weird because the equations do get rendered in visual mode and the source code, but not on my web browser.

I tried this workaround:

```
---
title: some title
format: 
  gfm:
    html-math-method: webtex
---
```

Which replaces the math equations with `webtex` images and it works, however when I add inline math, the equations can look a bit cluncky inside a paragraph.

Is there a way to render these equations without having to resort to the `webtex` method?